# ASP NET Label Get Dynamic Value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, label

I have a sample records of 4 student names:

1. John Doe
2. Jane Smith
3. Alice Johnson
4. Bob Anderson

I am having below html code which take a list of records from db and store:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StudentName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
        <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStudentName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StudentName") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
                <img src="../Images/copy.png" alt="Printer" onclick="copyLabelValue('lblStudentName')" class="col-2" style="cursor: pointer; width: 30px; height: 30px;" />
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and a javascript of

```
function copyLabelValue(label) {           
            var value = document.getElementById(label).innerText;
            navigator.clipboard.writeText(value);
}
```

but the value keeps returning the first name "John Doe" to me even when i trigerred the third/forth copy image. Tried some other ways but still couldnt get what i want which able to return me the third value if i pressed on the third copy image and vice versa.

Ways:

document.getElementById(label).innerText returns "John Doe"

document.getElementById('<%=lblStudentName.ClientID%>').innerText returns "John Doe"

$('#<%=lblStudentName.ClientID%>').html() returns "John Doe"

document.getElementById(label).innerHtml returns undefined

document.getElementById('<%=lblStudentName.ClientID%>').innerHtml returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you don't show if this is a repeater, gridview, or even a details view.

However, it probably does not matter.

The issue of course is that you don't have JUST ONE instance of the label, or the image or whatever. As a result each row is "repeated" many times , and in fact both the label, and your image button is ALSO repeated many times.

As a result, then each row of controls are actually "generated" and given a specific row ID. A great way to see how this works is to hit f12 (browser debug tools), select "elements", and then click on the "pointer" and now click on a element in the page - you see that EACH ROW of controls is given a specific name (usually prefixed by the control such as gridview, then the control name, and then a row number!).

So, there are several ways to do this. One simple way is to PASS the row value, and that's probably the most simple.

So, say this markup:

```
        <div style="float:left">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" 
                Width="55em">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <img src="../Content/copy.png" 
                                onclick="copyLabelValue('<%# Eval("HotelName") %>')"
                                style="width:48px;height:48px" 
                                />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;margin-left:40px">
            <h4>Paste test area</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
                TextMode="MultiLine" Height="117px" Width="304px"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>


        <script>
            function copyLabelValue(cText) {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(cText);

            }
        </script>
```

In above, I just pass the "expression" to the js code.

So, code to load is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GridView1.DataSource =
        MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GridView1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And the result is thus this:

[image]

However, let's say we want to grab the control on that grid row.

So, say this markup:

```
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblHotelName" runat="server" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' style="display:none"></asp:Label>

                            <img src="../Content/copy.png" id="myimagebtn" runat="server"
                                onclick="copyLabelValue2(this.id,'myimagebtn')"
                                style="width:48px;height:48px" 
                                />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And then this:

```
            function copyLabelValue2(btn, cText) {
                var tlbl = btn.replace(cText, 'lblHotelName')
                var HotelText = document.getElementById(tlbl).innerText
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(HotelText);
            }
```

There are other ways. I think often just passing the value using a server side expression works quite well. However, if the value has single (or double) quotes, then the code can fail.

As a result, it probably better to pass the "id" of the current control (make sure there is a runat="server", so the server side automatic control re-name occurs for each row of the repeater/gridview/listview (in fact any data repeating control).

Another possible trick? I often just make up a custom attribute for the control in question. This allows MULTIPLE values to be passed!

Say like this:

```
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <img src="../Content/copy.png" id="myimagebtn" runat="server"
                                onclick="copyLabelValue3(this)"
                                style="width:48px;height:48px" 
                                myHotel='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'
                                />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

And then this code:

```
            function copyLabelValue3(btn) {
                var HotelText = btn.getAttribute("myHotel")
                alert(HotelText)
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(HotelText);
            }
```

but, note that I could say pass Hotel and City by just adding another "made up" attribute

eg:

```
    <img src="../Content/copy.png" id="myimagebtn" runat="server"
        onclick="copyLabelValue3(this)"
        style="width:48px;height:48px" 
        myHotel='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>'
        myCity='<%# Eval("City") %>'
        />
```

However, since this means the data is being repeated (sent) to the browser 2 times, then with a large page, this would start to add additional payload to the web page. However, for a few extra values here and there, then adding "made up" attributes works rather well.

Comment: Sorry that i did not mentioned what view is this. But yes, i am using GridView to retrieve the value. Thanks for the advice on how to show gridview works. Your explanation are clear and definitely helpful! Appreciate your help on this so much!